# Connect to ODBC from Access (Newbie)

Tags: ms-access

I am spreading my wings into ODBC but need a kick-start. I have the SQL for the query and have ODBC installed (it works in Excel; that's how I got the SQL for the query). I need to know how to connect to the database from Access and pull the data into my table. Can someone please help with that?

Thank you,

Dave

Comment: If you can get to the data from Excel, you can get to it from Access. Likely there's an ODBC connection string involved in Excel. You might want to try setting up a DSN via the Access ODBC linked table definition (FILES | GET EXTERNAL DATA | LINK TABLES), but you'll have to know the server name and, perhaps, the appropriate logon credentials. You could also use TransferDatabase to create the links, but then you'd have to know the exact connect string.

Answer (score 0):

Do you wish to use Excel data in Access? If so, simply link the spreadsheet (External Data).

**EDIT** 
You can also link tables from other Access databases to easily create queries in the Query Design Window.

DAO is native for Access, here are a few notes:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = OpenCurrentDatabase("c:\docs\MyDb.mdb")
Set rs= db.OpenRecordset("Select Field From Table")

db.Execute "Update Table Set Field=2", dbFailOnError
```

Comment: I would prefer to just set up the query in Access. I need to compare the data to other data to make specialized reports. I want to skip the Excel step if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have MSAccess installed on this machine, so I might have the menu names incorrect.

If I understand correctly you're just trying to get MSAccess to connect to an ODBC database.

Go to the Main menu. Select "File"/"External Data"/"Link" ...

A wizard will step you through the connection set-up and show you the tables available in the database you're connecting to.

Once you've selected all the tables you want to work with, Access imports the definitions and they behave mostly like the local tables.

also see

http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Microsoft-Access/Importing-Data-into-MS-Access-with-ODBC/1/